# Using Laptop OS on Desktop

Tags: debian, hard-disk

So I have a dead laptop (defect graphiccard) and a dead desktop (defect HDD).
Now I just extracted the laptop HDD, put it in my desktop and booted up (writing from that right now).

Both OS are the same (Debian testing) but obviously the hardware differs (Both same architecture x64/amd64).

Generally speaking, is this approach ok, or am I missing something?

Things that come to mind:

- Drivers: Does Debian adapt to the new environment and chooses the right driver?
- Manually compiled software: Those would need immidiate recompilation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no fundamental problem with assembling computers from bits of other computers. It's even common to replace so many bits over time that the computer becomes a veritable [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) (in which case there are *so* many good and emotional arguments to be had about at which point the hostname must be changed because "it's not the same" anymore)!

> Drivers: Does Debian adapt to the new environment and chooses the right driver?

With all modern distribution kernels (i.e. unless you compiled your own kernel), yes. The distributions provide a kernel with a sufficient complement of drivers available in the initramfs to account for a wide variety of setups. Just make sure that the `MODULES` setting in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` is set to `most`, which is the default.

> Manually compiled software: Those would need immidiate recompilation?

I'm assuming that either both computers are `amd64` or both computers are `i386` (or even that the new one is `amd64` while the old one is `i386`, because hardware instruction set emulation for backward compatibility). If that's true, you're totally fine<sup>*</sup>. If that's not true, for example if one of the computers is PowerPC and the other one is some variety of ARM, then you can't even begin to do this at all for any software, never mind manually compiled software.

(<sup>*</sup>well, I suppose you *might* have compiled something manually with very specific flags to access unusual high-performance instructions that are present on one computer's CPU but not on the other, but this is atypical.)

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell about the architecture (because amd64 is so common, both are amd64). I eventually compiled some software to use 32bit (could have been steam^TM). So I should be fine.

/edit: graphiccard drivers that were installed manually would be problematic right? for example nvidia linux binary compared to ati linux drivers. (luckily in my case I only have ati/amd in both)

Comment: @Wandang As long as you leave some kind of generic driver installed (that is, don't delete the generic drivers after installing the proprietary ones), you may not get the best performance out of the graphics in a swap to a system with an incompatible GPU, but you'll still have _something_